# How to make AutoHotkey script for selecting a pen in OneNote(UWP)?

Tags: autohotkey

To give you an intro, I am not a programmer but a biologist who is learning a bit of programming.

Now I use OneNote a lot and continuously switch between typing and touch-based inking.

Now OneNote UWP does not have a shortcut for selecting a pen.

But I found out that by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and then <kbd>down</kbd> and then continuously pressing <kbd>right</kbd> six times and then pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, one can switch to pen via keyboard.

Now I want to automate the above process and link it to <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>.

So I tried AutoHotkey and tried to learn making a script of the above command but still no success.

This is what I tried (3-4 different ways):

```
Numpad1::
!d
Down
Right
Right
Right
Right
Right
Right
Right
Enter
```

I know this script is wrong but I can't find the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a good start! In order to send the keystrokes, you'll need to use one of the variations of the [Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) command. In addition, we can also make it so that it only work when OneNote is the active window using the [#If directive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm). (It makes hotkeys context-sensitive.)

I don't have OneNote on my machine, but please verify that the title contains "OneNote" for the following script to work.

```
SetTitleMatchMode , 2
#If WinActive("OneNote")
Numpad1::Send , !d{down}{right 6}{enter}
#If
```

---

**Edit:** I installed OneNote to try it out. It appears to run too quickly. I added a key delay of 75ms and changed `Send` to `SendEvent`, which obeys the key delay. This worked fine for me:

```
SetTitleMatchMode , 2
SetKeyDelay , 75
#If WinActive("OneNote")
Numpad1::SendEvent , !d{down}{right 6}{enter}
#If
```